# Error processing SPEL conditional expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a service and I'm trying to add a conditional expression using `@ConditionalOnExpression`.
I have two properties in my property file :
`module.enabled` which contains a boolean value
`my.datasource` which contains a string.

I want to have something like :
`module.enable is true AND my.datasource is not empty`

This is what I've tried so far :
`@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.datasource} != '' && ${module.enabled}")`

But I get a processing error exception.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it by writing like this

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty({"my.datasource", "module.enabled"})
@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "'${my.datasource}' != '' and ${module.enabled}")
class Config {
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Make sure you have `@ConditionalOnProperty({"my.datasource", "module.enabled"})` if you don't and the properties are not defined then `SpEL`
expression will be wronly evaluated and you might get `invalid expression exception`